# How to convert Particular number to time of the day Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

Can someone explain to me how I can convert a particular number to a time of the day in Java script. For example I have 3 to complete 3pm and 3am in javascript.

Comment: Can you be more specific in your example? For example, if the number is 3, does that represent 3am or 3pm and how do you decide which is which?

Comment: Is this homework?  Please supply some code to show what you have tried.  Your question makes no sense and does not adhere to SO guidelines [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I didn't try it yet doesn't matter about am pm can you let me know  is  this possible with moment js

Comment: Please update your question to make it more meaningful & give a more precise test case

Comment: if it is 3 then 3:00 AM and 15 then it is 3:00 PM, this is the standard, what you need is not clear. please clear your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question was pretty vague, but I think this will be helpful.

To get 3:00 am on the current day, you can run these 2 lines in javascript:

```
var today = new Date();
var newTime = new Date(today.getYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDay(), 3);
```

And to get 3:00 pm, this will work:

```
var newTime = new Date(today.getYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDay(), 15);
```

**Edit:**

Another way to set times is using `setHours(h, m, s, ms)`, where h = hours, m = minutes, s = seconds, and ms = miliseconds.

Example for setting time to 3:00am: (courtesy of @RobG)

```
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(3,0,0,0);
```

And 3:00 pm:

```
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(15,0,0,0);
```

[Reference to javascript Date object here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).

Comment: Or `var today = new Date(); today.setHours(3,0,0,0);` for 3 am. :-)